# ¿Cómo modificar el valor de un div, label o span con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, json

Con el siguiente ajax dentro de mi archivo **js**, con este ajax llamo datos de una consulta que hago a la base de datos dentro de un en un archivo **php**, al ponerlos en un input por un **id** me muestra los datos correctamente.

Pero, mi consulta es la siguiente : **¿Puedo pasar esos datos a una etiqueta label, div o span ?**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'seleccionarLicencia.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {licencia_id : id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
      $("#detalleReferencia").val.(response.referencia);
      $("#detalleNegocio").val(response.negocio);
      $("#detalleFecha_ini").val(response.fecha_ini);
      $("#detalleFecha_fin").val(response.fecha_fin);
      $("#editArea").val(response.area);
      $("#editEmail").val(response.email);
    }
});
```

Comment: para un div, por ejemplo, en lugar de val("lo que sea") será html("lo que sea")

Comment: Muchas gracias!. ya está, acabo de editar y me funcionó.

Comment: @track3r pon eso como respuesta (con algo de detalle sobre la diferencia entre los dos y los motivos de uno y otro)

Answer (score 2):

Tanto para los `div` como para los `label` y `span` podrías usar los métodos **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** o **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**.

```js
$("#etiqueta").text("Etiqueta editada");
$("#texto").html("Texto editado");

$("#contenedor").html("Prueba editada");
$("#contenedor2").text("Pruebaaaaaa");
$("#contenedor3").val("No funciona");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="etiqueta">Etiqueta</label>
<span id="texto">Texto</span>
<hr>
<div id="contenedor">Prueba</div>
<div id="contenedor2">Prueba</div>
<div id="contenedor3">Prueba</div>
```

Tal y como indica la documentación de JQuery para el método **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**:

> El método `.val()` es usado principalmente para obtener los valores de elementos del formulario como `input`, `select` y `textarea`. Cuando llamamos a una colección vacía, devuelve `undefined`.